# SQL Results in table cells grouped by date in <TR>

Tags: php, sql, html-table

I have a table in SQL Server with this fields and values.

```
ID_Employee | ID_Company | Date       | Concept | Hours
--------------------------------------------------------
      1     |      1     | 14/03/2013 |    1    |   8
      1     |      1     | 14/03/2013 |    2    |   0
      1     |      1     | 14/03/2013 |    3    |   3
      1     |      1     | 14/03/2013 |    4    |   1
      1     |      1     | 16/03/2013 |    1    |   5
      1     |      1     | 16/03/2013 |    2    |   2
      1     |      1     | 16/03/2013 |    3    |   0
      1     |      1     | 16/03/2013 |    4    |   0
```

What I need is to display the values where `ID_Employee=1` and `ID_Company=1` ​​in a HTML table grouping the rows by date, and ordering the hours in his column as the value of their concept.

```
Date       | Concept_1 | Concept_2 | Concept_3 | Concept_4 |
------------------------------------------------------------
14/03/2013 |  8 hours  |  0 hours  |  3 hours  |  1 hour   |
16/03/2013 |  5 hours  |  2 hours  |  0 hours  |  0 hours  |
```

I don't know how to do the query or what statement (while,for,foreach) to use in php to create 1 row (`<tr>`) for each different date, containing a single cell (`<td>`) for each concept and hour.

The html should look like this:

```
<tr id="14/03/2013">
    <td class="concept_1">8 hours</td>
    <td class="concept_2">0 hours</td>
    <td class="concept_3">3 hours</td>
    <td class="concept_4">1 hour</td>
</tr>
<tr id="16/03/2013">
    <td class="concept_1">5 hours</td>
    <td class="concept_2">2 hours</td>
    <td class="concept_3">0 hours</td>
    <td class="concept_4">0 hour</td>
</tr>
```

It may be easy, but now I'm a bit confused and I can't find the solution.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) See [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice), please.

Comment: You are trying to do a pivot. See: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/MySQL/Pivot_table

Comment: Are you using a popular development framework (e.g. cake, codeigniter etc)?

Comment: @Carlos I have improved my answer - now it is more similar to what you need

Comment: I did't know the concept of Pivot Table, it was just what I needed!
I don't have enought reputation to vote all answeres, but all were very useful! Thank you all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this:

```
declare @tableHTML nvarchar(MAX);
set @tableHTML = CAST((

    select  
        1 AS Tag,
        NULL AS Parent,
        pvt.[date] AS 'tr!1!id',
        ltrim(rtrim(str([1])))+ ' hours' AS 'tr!1!td class="concept_1"!Element',
        ltrim(rtrim(str([2])))+ ' hours' AS 'tr!1!td class="concept_2"!Element',
        ltrim(rtrim(str([3])))+ ' hours' AS 'tr!1!td class="concept_3"!Element',
        ltrim(rtrim(str([4])))+ ' hours' AS 'tr!1!td class="concept_4"!Element'
    from 
        (
            SELECT 
                date, 
                hours, 
                concept
            FROM table1
        ) p
    PIVOT
    (   
        AVG(hours)
        FOR concept IN
        ([1], [2], [3], [4]) 
    ) as pvt
    FOR XML EXPLICIT) AS NVARCHAR(MAX));

PRINT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@tableHTML, '</td class="concept_1">', '</td>'), '</td class="concept_2">', '</td>'), '</td class="concept_3">', '</td>'), '</td class="concept_4">', '</td>');
```

Ouput:

```
<tr id="2013-03-14">
    <td class="concept_1">8 hours</td>
    <td class="concept_2">0 hours</td>
    <td class="concept_3">3 hours</td>
    <td class="concept_4">1 hours</td>
</tr>
<tr id="2013-03-16">
    <td class="concept_1">5 hours</td>
    <td class="concept_2">2 hours</td>
    <td class="concept_3">0 hours</td>
    <td class="concept_4">0 hours</td>
</tr>
```

I used the pivot proposed by **@Sergio** - thanks a lot (+1)

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for a [PIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=SQL.105%29.aspx) operator wich allows you do desired stuff. You can use following query:

```
select  
    pvt.date,
    [1] AS concept_1,
    [2] AS concept_2,
    [3] AS concept_3,
    [4] AS concept_4
from 
    (
        SELECT 
            date, 
            hours, 
            concept
        FROM table1
    ) p
PIVOT
(   
    AVG(hours)
    FOR concept IN
    ([1], [2], [3], [4]) 
) as pvt
```

Providing [SqlFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c0a32/1) as well.